# NuGet downloads EF 6.1.2-beta alongside 6.1.1

Tags: entity-framework, nuget, entity-framework-6

I already had EntityFramework 6.1.1 in a couple of the projects in one of my solutions (data layer class libraries). Then I found out that I needed to install it in the main application as well, mainly to get the correct config data in place in app.config.

But when I selected **Manage NuGet packages for solution -> Entity Framework -> Manage** and selected the main application, NuGet started downloading and execute scripts from 6.1.2-beta2, even though 6.1.1 already was present in the solution. It also made the reference in the main application in packages.config reference 6.1.2-beta2 instead of 6.1.1.

The solution compiled, but when starting up I got a **TypeLoadException** pointing towards not being able to load type **TableExistenceChecker**.

After several hours of troubleshooting, I solved it by unloading the project, changing the assembly reference paths to point to v6.1.1 and then also manually hack the packages.config to reference 6.1.1.

Is this really correct behavior? I prefer to stay clear of the prereleases since this software is running in production environment.

If this is indeed a bug, where should I report it? I've never had trouble with NuGet or EF like this before.